# Telerik MVC File Upload - "OnError" not called even if Response status is set to 401

Tags: telerik, telerik-mvc

I am using Telerik MVC File Upload to upload files on to server. I was expecting that if I return response status code other than 200, the "OnError" JavaScript handler would be triggered. However, the "OnError" callback is not getting invoked when I set the response status code to 401. Is this the default behaviour of the Telerik MVC Upload component or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of the Telerik ASP.NET MVC Extensions are you using? I believe this (OnError event not firing) was resolved in the Q2 2011 SP1 (2011.2.914) release of the components, which was released even to the open source license holders. You can download that version [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/general/q2-2011-sp1.aspx). Keep in mind that the Q3 2011 release is around the corner, with a public beta currently being out and about. For more information on the beta you can go [right here](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/11-10-27/telerik-mvc-q3-2011-beta-preview-new-charting-and-grid-features-and-better-mobile-support.aspx).

Comment: I am using Q2-2-725, so as you pointed out, I will need to upgrade my application to use Q2-2-914. Thanks for the help.